# maven is unable to clean up spring 5.0.5 jars from intellij when i changed version to 4.3.16

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I was trying to upgrade to spring 5.0.5. Now when i reverted pom.xml file back (to version 4.3.16) maven is unable to clean up  spring 5.0.5 jars from Intellij Idea.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xfCw.png)

How can i clean up the 5.0.5 imported jars?

Comment: Reload the configuration in IDEA...

Comment: After you have changed the pom.xml, [synchronize](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_import_dependency) it's changes with IDE configuration.